# Create upload to Onedrive button

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, upload, onedrive

I am trying to create an "upload to OneDrive" button on my website, knowing that I would just like this to open a user authentication window (so that the user can upload the file created on my website directly on its own Onedrive cloud.

I have already done the same thing with google drive but so simply that I do not understand why I can not find a solution for my problem with "OneDrive" (and dropbox also for that matter ..)

my language is : nodeJs/python/Js

Answer (score -1):

Create a database to store the files. Try using mondodb (a node package) to create a database to store uploaded files.